# select2 height wrong?

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a select2 listbox looking like this:

[image: select2]

The first value is empty and it works alright but the box doesn't seem high enough.

I make the following call to create it:

```
$elem.select2({minimumResultsForSearch: 10, placeholder: undefined, width: 'resolve'});
```

This is the HTML before the select2 is called:

```
<select class="select required" id="user_transaction_company_user_id" name="user_transaction[company_user_id]"><option value=""></option>
<option value="17">enza rinaldi</option>
<option value="14">stijn verrept</option></select>
```

I see that there is an empty value first, that's no problem but it should dispplay it correctly, not half the height.

Answer (score 1):

you should define a placeholder option, it will remove the empty option and display the placeholder when no value is selected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  But I don't want to display the posibility to select an empty value.  Something needs to be filled in at all times.

Comment: if something needs to be filled in all the time why are you adding an empty option to your select?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want an empty option that can be selected after another option has been selected you can fill the option with

```
&nbsp
```

to make it full height.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to set a default value (by default the first option of your selectbox), you need an empty value in your options. If you then set a placeholder when initialising select2, select2 will automatically replace this empty option with the placeholder text (this placeholder can be blank). Once the user selects an option, there is no way to choose the empty option anymore (unless you specify allowClear: true).

In code (assuming an empty option is set as follows):

```
<option value=""></option>
```

After choosing an option, user cannot choose the empty option anymore:

```
$elem.select2({ placeholder: "" });
```

After choosing an option, user is able to deselect/choose the empty option:

```
$elem.select2({ placeholder: "", allowClear: true });
```